# Why isn't vim reading my global configuration file?

Tags: 10.04, vim

I put 'start' in `~/.vimrc`, and my vim starts in input mode.

I put 'start' in `/etc/vimrc`, and nothing happens, for any user, including root.

How do I fix this?

UPDATE:

per **queueoverflow** below, I consulted `:help system-vimrc`, which I interpreted to mean that the most common path is indeed `/etc/vimrc` but the system is actually computing that from `$VIM/vimrc`.

`echo $VIM` produces blank output for both a normal user and for root.

This is a fresh Ubuntu 10.04 LTS installation, did I do something wrong?

I installed vim with `sudo apt-get install vim`.

Comment: See `:help system-vimrc`.

From http://serverfault.com/questions/82626/how-to-make-a-global-vimrc

Comment: @queueoverflow I updated the question in response to your comment, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't the correct path in `/etc/vim/vimrc`? You are missing the middle vim.

Comment: This was my problem. Sometimes you just need a second set of eyes. Thanks.

Comment: I think /etc/vim/vimrc.local is even better, it gets sourced by /etc/vim/vimrc

Comment: Maybe one reason people get this wrong (me included) is that this is listed wrong on the #1 hit in Google for /etc/vimrc, http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/vimrc.html