# Vim change colorscheme and vimrc location file

Tags: vim, colors

I am under Ubuntu 11.04 and when I type vim -v in the shell I get this:

```
 version 7.3.35
```

First, I want to say that I don't see any file called **vimrc** under my home folder. Is this normal behavior? I just see one in `/etc/vim`

I have added `colors delek` at the end of the mentioned vimrc file (and I have d**elek.vim** in `/usr/share/vim/vim73/colors`) but when I restart vim, I don't see that scheme.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is normal, and you can create the .vimrc file yourself (remember the '.' at the beginning of the file). You can add any VIM options to this file, and there are many guides online for things you can add/do to tweak your .vimrc for a specific use.

Comment: But, why wouldn't I see the colors scheme if I add in the that other vimrc file?

Comment: Check this answer out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/60041/why-isnt-vim-reading-my-global-configuration-file

Comment: I changed /etc/vim/vimrc as the answer suggested and I still can't see the colorscheme.

Comment: you could also try putting the colorscheme file in ~/.vim (that's where I save mine).